# Share variables between makefiles

Tags: makefile

I have a directory structure where I want one main makefile in my main folder, and then another makefile in both my test and src folder.

In my main makefile, I have directives for both test / all that call the individual folder makefiles. I'm trying to declare variables in my main makefile and have them accessible to those other folders.

For instance in my main Makefile

```
PACKAGES = jansson mysql ....

all:
    do something here

test:

    cd test
    make test
```

And then in my test/Makefile I want to be able to access the previous PACKAGES variable and add this makefile's individual dependencies onto it.

In the test/Makefile

```
PACKAGES += googletest googlemock

test
     do something here
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create another file, for instance `Makefile.variable` where those shared variables are defined and include the file using

```
include $(PATHTOSHAREDMAKEFILE)/Makefile.variable
```

Look at the [include manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) for more information

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the variable on the command-line:

```
test:
    make -C test PACKAGES="$(PACKAGES)"
```

Note that it's not possible to go the other way around though. If the `test/Makefile` changes a variable, then these changes can't come back to the calling makefile.

---

If you want to add to the `PACKAGES` variable in the main makefile, you will have to refactor your build system to include sub-makefiles instead. So the main makefile sets everything up, then includes (using the `include` directive available in most make implementations) the sub-makefiles which adds specific targets local to them, as well as alter/add variables.

For example, lets say you have two test directories, `test_foo` and `test_bar`, you could have a variable containing the test targets, lets call it `TEST_TARGETS`. Each makefile in the `test_*` folder adds its local and unique target to the global variable and the main makefile can then run them.

Something like this:

Main makefile:

```
# Start empty
TEST_TARGETS =

include test_foo/Makefile
include test_bar/Makefile

test:
    for target in "$(TEST_TARGETS)"; do \
        $(MAKE) $(target); \
    done
```

test_foo/Makefile:

```
TEST_TARGETS += test_foo

test_foo:
    # Do some foo testing
```

test_bar/Makefile:

```
TEST_TARGETS += test_bar

test_bar:
    # Do some bar testing
```

Comment: The problem I see with the last approach is that $(MAKE) $(target) is called with the path at the top-level Makefile directory. I would think that the path needs to be in the folder with the Makefile that contains the target of interest in order for this to work properly.

Comment: Yes, I have this problem where I have two makefiles in different directories and using the include directive changes the value of the imported variables relative to the main make's path and this breaks the build. Any workaround?

Comment: @JCSB Not really since I don't know enough details. I recommend posting a question about it, with as many details of the environment, makefile-setup and dependencies, and the "problem" you have and how it breaks your build.

Answer (score -1):

export PACKAGES = jansson mysql ....